# Locally smoothed mean - R GPlots bandplot - how to get the values?

Tags: r

I am using the bandplot function from [gplots](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gplots/gplots.pdf).

```
install.packages("gplots")
library("gplots")

x <- abs(rnorm(500))
y <- rnorm(500, mean=2*x, sd=2+2*x)
bandplot(x,y)
```

[image]

Is there any way to get the values plotted by bandplot?
the manual says

```
Invisibly returns a list containing the x,y points plotted for each line.
```

but I cannot find the values.

```
> b = bandplot(x,y)
> b
NULL
```

=> I want to find the locally smoothed mean (the red line in the bandplot) to make prediction for a given x.

Comment: The function does return `NULL` only. If you want it to return the values, you have to modify the code.

Comment: The part of this question that is not a duplicate is the part referring to `R` coding, which you may ask on SO.